# APT_AUTOGEN setting just affecting the package being installed or all?

Tags: apt, rootkit, rkhunter

I have got `rkhunter` version `1.4.2`, and I was just wondering about the `APT_AUTOGEN` option which I currently have enabled. Does this mean that when I install new software that it just adds that software to the kind of 'whitelist' or does it mean that it adds all software to the 'whitelist' that has been newly installed etc?

So basically if I installed a rootkit (not through APT), and then I installed some normal software through apt with the `APT_AUTOGEN` on, would that mean that when running a rootkit scan with `rkhunter` that it would not detect the rootkit, or would it just mean that that particular software that I installed through APT will be not detected as being bad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having the `APT_AUTOGEN` option enabled means that when you install or remove software using APT that the changes made are added to the `rkhunter` file properties database (a bit like a whitelist) to make false positives less likely. It does not however update the file properties database with all new changes to the system, so if you did install a rootkit (not through APT), and then you installed some other software through APT (not a rootkit), then if you did a scan (with `rkhunter`) and the rootkit was a known rootkit it would be picked up, as only the software which you installed through APT would have been added to the file properties database, and not any other changes in your system.